# Simulating CSS Column vertical content flow by re-ordering elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

I have an unordered list with approx 50 li elements that is displayed in a four column grid with the addition of media queries that change the column count at different widths.

To support IE8&9, I am using fallback CSS and Modernizr to float the li elements left and specify widths and margin which simulates the CSS Column layout.

The only difference is that the items flow horizontally rather than vertically.

I want to perform some sort of "grid sort" re-shuffling of the `$('.main-index li')` array so that that the li elements run in an order like 1,14,27,40,2,15,28,41,3... rather than 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...

I have not got far, but this is that start I've made...

```
if (!Modernizr.csscolumns) {

    // If CSS Columns is not supported, re-order li elements 
    // instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8... reorder to 1,14,27,40,2,15,28,41,3...

    var columnCount = $('.main-index li').css('column-count'); // = 4
    var itemCount = $('.main-index li').length; // = 50
}
```

I've included a jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pLLe9e9L/1/) that i'm using to test.

Comment: Take a look at this http://pterkildsen.com/2012/12/08/css3-columns-in-internet-explorer-7-8-and-9/

Comment: @kursus I initially tried using a polyfill based on the same code (https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn) but found that it's not compatible with CSS containing media queries. I was getting the same error as [this](https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn/issues/9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this good enough?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // If CSS Columns is not supported, re-order li elements 
  // instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8... reorder to 1,14,27,40,2,15,28,41,3...
  var items = $('.main-index li');
  var columnCount = $('.main-index ul').css('column-count'); // = 4
  if ( typeof columnCount != 'number' ) {
    columnCount = 4;
  }
  var itemCount = items.length; // = 5

  function reflow() {
    var rowCount = Math.ceil(itemCount / columnCount);
    items.detach();
    $('.main-index ul').empty(); // Prevent build-up of dummy items
    for (var row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
      for (var column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {
        var index = row + (column * rowCount);

        if ( index >= itemCount ) {
          $('.main-index ul').append('<li class="dummy">');
        } else {
          $('.main-index ul').append(items[index]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    var newColumnCount = $('.main-index ul').css('column-count'); // = 4
    if ( typeof newColumnCount != 'number' ) {
      newColumnCount = 4;
    }
    if ( newColumnCount != columnCount ) {
      columnCount = newColumnCount;
      reflow();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Peter, this is great, thanks. I'll be able to use this. Can you see why item 13 is in the wrong place? https://jsfiddle.net/pLLe9e9L/3/

Comment: Yes, it's because there is no item 51 (which would otherwise sit between 38 and 13, pushing 13 onto the next line.

Comment: The easiest fix I can think of it to check whether `index` is greater than `items.length`, and if so, to insert a "dummy" list item.

Comment: I've updated the js to add that fix - you may want to update the css to hide the dummy items (visibility:hidden rather than display:none should work)

Comment: One warning is that this breaks if a resize changes the number of columns. You could maybe fix that by keeping the `items` variable around and re-applying this at certain resize thresholds.

Comment: Hi @peter, can you please suggest a way that I can reapply the code on a breakpoint change of column-count? I tried wrapping the code in a function and calling on window resize but I couldn't see a way to reset the list back to the original order

Comment: I've added a window resize check. It relies on keeping the items (in their original order) as a closure variable. I used `if ( typeof newColumnCount != 'number' ) { newColumnCount = Math.floor((window).width() / 220); }` to test it on jsFiddle